# Iterating a List in an Object Initializer

Tags: c#

When building an object with the object initializer syntax, is there a way to iterate over a list in one of the assignment statements and assign an output of the iteration to that property?

For example, I have a Person model which I'm converting into a Person view model (mostly because the Person model has lazy-loaded properties and is highly and potentially recursively dynamic, but the view is disconnected over the web and just needs a single Person instance to be serialized).  I'm also using the nVentive Umbrella extensions for handy things like `.ForEach()` on enumerables.  So to output my list of Person view models from my Person models, I convert them like this:

```
people.ForEach(p =>
  returnPeople.Add(
    new Person{
      FirstName = p.FirstName,
      ID = p.ID,
      LastName = p.LastName,
      MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
      NamePrefix = p.NamePrefix,
      NameSuffix = p.NameSuffix,
      ParentsID = p.Parents == null ? 0 : p.Parents.ID,
      PartnershipIDs = new List<int>(),
      Sex = p.Sex.ToString()
    }
  )
);
```

I'm iterating over the collection of Person models (`people`) and populating the collection of Person view models (`returnPeople`).  Everything works fine, but I also want to populate that `PartnershipIDs` property in the same statement.  Functionality such as:

```
//....
PartnershipIDs = p.Partnerships.ForEach(par => yield return par.ID)
//....
```

That, however, doesn't work.  The compiler doesn't like the syntax.  But is there a way to accomplish that functionality in this setup?  Or do I have to initialize the Person view model with all but one field first, and then on the next line populate the remaining field?

Comment: What's wrong with a good old proper `foreach` loop ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a simple projection:

```
PartnershipIDs = p.Partnerships.Select(par => par.ID).ToList()
```

Comment: Simple enough (and I really should have thought of that...), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of doing a `ForEach`, you do a `Select`:

```
PartnershipIDs = p.Partnerships.Select(par => par.ID).ToList();
```